# How to get X and Y indexes of the current tile in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, openmaptiles

I'm using Mapbox GL JS to display a map using my own tile-server (which just serves openmaptiles `pbf` files in a `Z/X/Y` directory structure).

The loading of tiles is done automatically, based on the current center coordinates.

I want to pre-load the surrounding tiles for an offline solution.
I know how to get the current zoom-level with `map.getZoom()`

How can I get the X and Y indexes of the current tile URL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest framing the problem in terms of geographic coordinates:

- You can get the viewport geographic coordinates from [`Map#getBounds`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#getBounds))
- You can convert geographic coordinates to tile coordinates with some [light math](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you need to do some calculations in bash scripts, you can use [mercantile](https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile) library or CLI utility to transform lon/lan coordinates to tiles, find parent or children tiles and get some other information. Another advanced tool is [supermercado](https://github.com/mapbox/supermercado).

Answer (score 1):

[@mapbox/tile-cover](https://github.com/mapbox/tile-cover) can be used to figure out what tiles are included in a given geometry. Once you get the bounds of the map with `Map#getBounds()`, you can then figure out the tile coverage using `@mapbox/tile-cover`. I also use `@turf/bbox-polygon` to create a geometry from the given map bounds. For example:

```
import cover from '@mapbox/tile-cover';
import bboxPolygon from '@turf/bbox-polygon';
import { flatten } from 'lodash';

const zoom = Math.floor(map.getZoom());
const tiles = cover.tiles(
  bboxPolygon(flatten(map.getBounds().toArray()) as BBox).geometry,
  {
    min_zoom: zoom,
    max_zoom: zoom,
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

It's a React.js implementation.

```
const lon2tile = (lon: any, zoom: any) => {
  return Math.floor(((lon + 180) / 360) * Math.pow(2, zoom))
}
const lat2tile = (lat: any, zoom: any) => {
  return Math.floor(
    ((1 -
      Math.log(Math.tan((lat * Math.PI) / 180) + 1 / Math.cos((lat * Math.PI) / 180)) / Math.PI) /
      2) *
      Math.pow(2, zoom)
  )
}

const zoomToUse = Math.floor(mapZoom)
const currentX = mapBounds?.ne && lon2tile((mapBounds.ne as TLngLatLike).lng, zoomToUse)
const currentY = mapBounds?.sw && lat2tile(Math.abs((mapBounds.sw as TLngLatLike).lat), zoomToUse)
const currentZ = zoomToUse
```

And this is how I call the tiles API to check first if valid tiles are returned for the current x, y, z:

```
  let tilesURLWithCoordinates = tiles.replace("{z}", zoomToUse.toString())
  tilesURLWithCoordinates = tilesURLWithCoordinates.replace("{x}", currentX.toString())
  tilesURLWithCoordinates = tilesURLWithCoordinates.replace("{y}", currentY.toString())

  const response = await fetch(tilesURLWithCoordinates, {
    method: "GET",
  })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).