# Is there a way to sync Mapbox canvas and Konva canvas coordinate system

Tags: javascript, mapbox, konvajs

The problem is that Konva uses x/y coordinate system, while Mapbox uses geo coordinates.

Comment: Look into "projections" and the math behind it. Likely tho Mapbox has an API for converting to X/Y. See here to continue your journey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638043/how-to-get-x-and-y-indexes-of-the-current-tile-in-mapbox-gl-js